# val('') clears the field but value remains

Tags: javascript, html, validation

### What I want

When I submit a form, this specific field must to turn empty if the value is invalid.
I have this function that validate the value and set it empty if necessary.

### The problem

When I try to submit the form with an invalid value the function clears the field and it seems to work, but if I click again to submit the form the old value (that doesn't apears in the field anymore) kinda bypasses the validation and is inserted into the database.
The `val('')` is cleaning the field but somehow the value remains.

### The code

Here is the code I am using:

```
if (response==true) {
    $("#license").val('');
}
```

### What I already tried

```
document.getElementById('license').value = "" // didn't work at all
```

```
$("#license").val(' '); // with one space but I lose the placeholder visualization, and I need it
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to check the developer tools in your browser to see what's actually being sent to the server. If you clear out the value of a form field, it's going to be cleared out. You may have another form field with the same name, or you may have a bug in your server code.

Comment: When submitting you need to prevent submitting not only clear the boxes. If you just clear them, values are still submitted.

Comment: Please include your html so we can help determine what's going on.

Comment: Specifics would help, what are you considering as an invalid value? Do you want to restrict a field to numbers or letters only or are you looking to compare entries against a list of acceptable values you already have?